# Scroll-able Div does not wrap around content

Tags: html, css, scroll

```html
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll; height: 200px; width: 200px">
  <div style="border-color: black; height: 100px; width: 30px; border: 2px; border-style: solid; position:absolute; left: 20px; top: 200px">
  </div>
</div>
```

I would expect that the div inside the scroll-able div doesn't show up outside the scroll-able div. 
How can I archive this ? The Rectangle should only be visible in the scroll-able div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to reset position, either for the parent or the child : example below

```css
/* CSS here for demo purpose to put both example side by side*/
body {
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
grid-auto-flow:row dense;
 
}
body>*{grid-column:1;margin:auto;}
body >:nth-child(2) ~ * {grid-column:2;}
```

```html
<p>position relative on parent,<br><b> so the parent becomes the reference for the absolute child</b></p>
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll; height: 200px; width: 200px;position:relative;">
  <div style="border-color: black; height: 100px; width: 30px; border: 2px; border-style: solid; position:absolute; left: 20px; top: 200px">
  </div>
</div>
<p> static position on children<br><b> so it is part of the flow</b></p>
<div style="overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll; height: 200px; width: 200px">
  <div style="border-color: black; height: 100px; width: 30px; border: 2px; border-style: solid; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 200px">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative` to the top div

```html
<div style="position: relative; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll; height: 200px; width: 200px">
  <div style="border-color: black; height: 100px; width: 30px; border: 2px; border-style: solid; position:absolute; left: 20px; top: 200px">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Snippet Demo:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 30px;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 20px;
  
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Absolutely positioned elements* Are removed from their parents, and displayed over the DOM. Remove `position:absolute;` and change your `top` and `left` to `margin-top` and `margin-left`

```css
.one{
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  overflow-x: scroll; 
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px"
}

.two{
  border-color: black; 
  height: 100px; 
  width: 30px; 
  border: 2px; 
  border-style: solid; 
  margin-left: 20px; 
  margin-top: 200px
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
  </div>
</div>
```